# Are there toilets on the long-distance Translink trains in Queensland?

Tags: trains, public-transport, brisbane, queensland, sunshine-coast

Most of the trains operated by Translink in/around Brisbane / South-East Queensland seem to travel fairly short distances. The ones I've taken within the Brisbane area don't have toilets on them, presumably because of the short travel times.

However, not all Translink trains are like that. Those [serving the Sunshine coast have longer journeys](http://jp.translink.com.au/travel-information/network-information/trains/T/sunshine-coast-line), with a journey like Nambour to Brisbane taking around 2 hours, and Gympie North to Brisbane around 3.

I've tried looking on the [Translink page for "Hour to use the train"](http://translink.com.au/travel-information/how-to/how-to-use-the-train), but it doesn't mention anything about toilets.

Do these long distance (2-3 hour journey) Translink trains have toilets on board?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As per some other reviews online](http://www.discover-sunshine-coast-australia.com/Translink.html):

> Some of the trains are fitted with luggage racks and toilet facilities
>   (usually located behind the drivers cabin or near the guard's cabin)

And last year there was a drive to [improve the toilet facilities that did exist, where they existed](http://translink.com.au/content/tackling-toilet-troubles):

> Transport and Main Roads Minister Scott Emerson said it is reasonable
>   for passengers to expect the most basic amenities on our train
>   network, particularly on longer services.
>
> “Having travelled on the Sunshine Coast line many times before I
>   understand how frustrating and inconvenient it can be when toilets are
>   not available,” Mr Emerson said.
>
> “From today, trains with toilet facilities will be prioritised to the
>   Sunshine Coast line with particular focus on those busy morning and
>   afternoon peak services.

So while not all do, the busy peak trains are more likely to have them, and as of last year, are more likely to be functioning(!).

Answer (score 2):

Most trains coming down and up along the Gold Coast (an hour to an hour and a half journey) are serviced with possibly 1-3 toilets on board. These are usually located on the *outside* edge, i.e. furthest from one end or the other on the inside of the carriage. They are very well kept and quite large. Though you may have to jump out out of the train at one stop and back into the appropriate carriage and then back again... But well worth it for the service it provides.

Answer (score 2):

I had to travel from Mooloolaba to Brisbane which is 35 minutes to Landsborough on the bus then approx. one and a half hours to Brisbane by train. I did not need to go to the toilet when I boarded the train but soon after I needed to go but the toilet was locked. I then had to wait one and a half hours and was absolutely busting but I could not get off the train because I needed to get to a job interview in Brisbane. I had no choice but I simply could not wait and ended up wetting my pants just before Roma St station. I have never complained officially to anyone but I blame Translink, especially as I ended up being late for the interview anyway and didn't get the job.

Comment: How does this not answer the question? +1

Comment: This is basically saying there are toilets but I found them locked.